# Terraformのローカル変数とVariableはどう使い分けますか？

Tags: aws, terraform

Terraformの変数について、お尋ねさせてください。
ローカル変数とVariableはどう使い分けますか？

また、Variableはなぜ外部から変更可能なのでしょうか？
（Variableの中に入れる変数を、いつでも書き換えられるように、別途ファイルを作るということですか？それはローカル変数でも同じではないでしょうか・・・？）

初学者のため、散漫な質問文で申し訳ございません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Terraform の [input variables](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables) は module を定義するときに使うものです。Module を使う側に立ってみると、ソースコードは変えずにちょっとした設定値だけ変えて使いたくなることはよくあり、そういった場合に値を外部から注入する目的で使われるものです。Module を関数のようなものだと思うと、input variables は関数の引数のようなものになります。

対して [local values](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/locals) は計算した値に一時的な名前を付けるだけのものです。関数の中で使うローカル変数のようなもので、同じ値がベタ書きされるのを防ぎ、名前をつけて意味を持たせる役割を果たします。Input variables と異なり、リソースの attribute や他の local value を参照して代入することもできます。再代入はできないです。

ちょっと長くて遠回りなのですが、Terraform modules を作るチュートリアルをやってみるのが理解しやすいと思います: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/modules/module

Answer (score 3):

次のような違いがあり、それらを踏まえて使い分けします。（ひとまず`module`については置いときます。）

## `variable`

- 実行開始時に指定する
- コマンドライン引数、環境変数、`.tfvars`などさまざまな方法で指定可能
- バリデーションが可能
- 他の変数を参照できない

## `local`

- 計算値
- バリデーションがない
- 他の`local`、`variable`、`resource`、`data`などを参照できる